How does the signal value change if it's own value is used to calculate it?
I am a am currently studying VHDL and I have encountered an interesting problem.
I have created an entity Sklop with the architecture Beh2:
entity Sklop is 
   port ( 
   x : in bit; 
   y : in bit; 
   z : out bit 
); 
end Sklop; 

architecture Beh2 of Sklop is 
   signal a, b : bit; 
begin 
   a <= x; 
   b <= not b and a; 
   z <= (a or b) xor y; 
end Beh2;

I have this sample time diagram of the signals here:

I am interested how will the signal b change if it depends on itself.
Presume a is '1'. To my understanding, not b is immidiately assigned to '1' since b is initially '0'. Then b will register the change of not b and change it's value to 1 after delta. However, once the new value of b is assigned, not b will then immidiately change it's value to 0 which b will again register and after delta assign itself the value 0. The process will loop indefinitely. Is this how the process is supposed to go or am I misunderstanding something?

Your understanding of the process is correct as signal b depends on itself.
If u presume value of a is 1 and b is 0.
b <= not b and a; 

b <= not 0 and 1
b <= 1 and 1
b <= 1 ; this will be used after delta.

Next cycle:

b <= not 1 and 1
b <= 0 and 1
b <= 0

The value of b will toggle after each delta period.
This expression can even lead to the Race Condition.
Signals are updated at the end of the current delta cycle in VHDL. This means that the signal b will be evaluated before its assignment is scheduled. However, when you use not b in the expression, you are reading the current value of b (before the new assignment happens), but then trying to assign a new value to b in the same process cycle.

There is no race condition here. The value of b is always known in the current delta, so there is no ambiguity. race conditions only occur when the order of assignments is unknown. This is not the case with signals.

Signal updates scheduled in a projected output waveform occur at the soonest at the beginning of the next simulation cycle with a default delay of 0. After signal updates any processes sensitive to signal events resume and execute until subsequently suspend in wait statements including the implicit last wait statement of a process with a sensitivity list. It can take some number of delta cycles for a model to quit scheduling updates subsequently advancing simulation time until the next scheduled time. Concurrent assignment statements represent equivalent process statements.
